# Is there any way to inform the host starting time and ending time of a method execution in Java Card?

Tags: javacard

Assume that there are some methods in the `process` method of a Java Card applet and It is important for you to know when a specific one starts to run[=execute] (i.e. when it called) and when it end. In this situation, is there any way to inform the host(reader/user) in the points of method calling and method exiting?

For example, in the following program, it is important for me to know when `Method2` started to execute and when it ended :

```
public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {
    if (selectingApplet()) {
        return;
    }
    Method1(apdu);
    Method2(apdu);
    Method3(apdu);
}
```

Comment: (A bit late, but...) If simulating card tear is all you want. Can't you just place `while(true);` at the desired point and tear the card manually?

Comment: @vlp Good idea. Thanks. Actually I can't remember what exactly I wanted to do with it. But I think I wanted to make card tears during execution of `requestObjectDeletion()` method. So adding an infinite while loop won't be helpful, because I can't distinguish execution of that specific method (`requestObjectDeletion`) from the `while(true);` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaCard has no internal clock (because there is no battery inside your smart card).

To measure execution time of your `Method2(apdu)` you should:

1. Measure the whole APDU execution time in the reader.
2. Comment out `Method2` and measure the whole APDU again.
3. Compare results.

You can find out the approximate start time and end time of `Method2` in a similar way (commenting out and measuring the difference). Diagnostics of JavaCard code are never easy, unfortunately.

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks. But I want to know when it starts and when it ends. (For example I want to do a card tearing during the execution of this method). So the time of execution is not the point. the start point and end point matters. Is not there any way to inform the user with a SW for example? In the other word is there any way to send a data twice( separate) per one process method calling?

Comment: Tell more what you want to do. Why don't you use Try-catch, in order to catch exception occurred by tearing?

Comment: Usually when a card tear happens the card can do preciously little, as it loses all power. One trick to correctly calculate timing is to perform a method in a loop, possibly remove some APDU overhead (which you can also test using a loop) and then divide by the number of iterations. That way you can pretty accurately calculate the time for the Applet / OS / chip combination.

Comment: @HBizhi As I said, I want to do a card tear exactly when the JCVM running method2! So I need to know when this method starts and when it ends.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Isn't there any way to announce the user method2 starts to run?

Answer (score 1):

There is no online logs in Java Cards. Cause it's not a IDEA installed on your windows to show you a server log, something like sysout logs.
The only way of communication between oncard and offcard applications is APDU.
There's two way that maybe you can use them to reach whatever you want:

1) Simple way. If you want to test Method2 for tearing just use different instructions for each method. Means that use InsX for Method2 and if applet receives an APDU with InsX then call Method2. Now you know when Method2 is calling and you can test tearing in parallel.

2) You can work with logical channels and use multiselectable applets. In this solution you can have two applets in selectable mode at the same time, you can use other applet to send you an APDU whenever you want. For more information about logical channels refer [here](http://askra.de/software/jcdocs/app-notes-2.2.1/logchan.html).

Comment: I am familiar with logical channels and multiSelectable interface, but for the second solution I think I must use SIO also, right? As far as I understand from your answer, you mean I can select App1 in primary channel, App2 in channel 2 and App3 in channel3. And after that I call MethodX of App2 in the first line of Method2 and call MethodY of App3 in the last line of this method. right? So when Method2 in primary channel called, it call MethodX in start and MethodY in ends. And these shared methods returns `S` and `E` for example. Did I got the point? If you mean that, you are so genius! :D

Comment: each `process` method call returns only one APDU response? Isn't there any way to return more? (Without using other applet)

Comment: Although I got what you are asking but the question you asked is wrong, cause each `process` method definitely can returns as many APDU responses as you want. But if you want to return two APDUs, at the beginning and end of a method, called method2, and expecting the method to be processed after the first return, you can't. Because after returning an APDU you havn't got the handle to method2 and method2 stops from processing any further.

Comment: Do you mean I can put an infinite while in my `process` method and return an string forever in response of only one APDU command?!

Comment: I didn't mean any thing in the last comment. I just wanted to say that you can't return two APDU responses sequentially, one after another, in the begining and end of a method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73184/discussion-between-abraham-and-hbizhi).

Comment: Sometimes you can get information through a debug interface, which is sometimes present on a card or emulator. You probably need vendor support to get or enable such an interface though.

Comment: (A bit late, but I am quite curious...) are you sure that you can process an APDU on a different logical channel while another channel is already processing one (i.e. has not sent Response-APDU yet)? AFAIK this violates the lower layer 7816-3 protocols...And (AFAIK) there is only a single APDU buffer present in the JCRE.